# jQuery .hover() performance doubts

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, variables, hover

While I know some jQuery to simplify front-end manipulation programming, I also aware of some of some "best practices" to level up the performance on browser, like caching through `var` and always descend from ID selectors. But I have doubts about this piece of code. Could it be done better?

Preamble: This code animates several blocks inside the (already cached) selector through .hover().

The HTML is something like this:

```
<div clas="block-link red">(...)</div>
<div clas="block-link yellow">(...)</div>
<div clas="block-link magenta">(...)</div>
<div clas="block-link moradopelusa">(...)</div>
```

And the jQuery to animate at hovering inside one of them:

```
var cached_blocks = jQuery(.block-link);

jQuery(cached_blocks).hover(function(){
    var this_block = jQuery(this),
        this_block_text = jQuery(this_block).children(div.text),
        this_block_image = jQuery(this_block).children(div.image),
        this_block_link = jQuery(this_block).children(div.link),
        this_block_link_icon = jQuery(this_block_link).children(a.icon);

    /* Animate in; show everything */
    jQuery(this_block_text).animate(..);
    jQuery(this_block_image).animate(..);
    jQuery(this_block_link).animate(..);
    jQuery(this_block_link_icon).animate(..);

}, function() {
    var this_block = jQuery(this),
        this_block_text = jQuery(this_block).children(div.text),
        this_block_image = jQuery(this_block).children(div.image),
        this_block_link = jQuery(this_block).children(div.link),
        this_block_link_icon = jQuery(this_block_link).children(a.icon);

    /* Animate out; put everything where they belong */
    jQuery(this_block_text).animate(..);
    jQuery(this_block_image).animate(..);
    jQuery(this_block_link).animate(..);
    jQuery(this_block_link_icon).animate(..);
});
```

I'm seeing that I am declaring variables again after hover, but I don't know any technique to not doing again. Anyway, even that way it works like a charm.

**Update:** Fixed Code #1

```
var cached_blocks = jQuery(.block-link);

jQuery(cached_blocks).on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(){
    var this_block = jQuery(this),
        this_block_text = jQuery(this_block).children(div.text),
        this_block_image = jQuery(this_block).children(div.image),
        this_block_link = jQuery(this_block).children(div.link),
        this_block_link_icon = jQuery(this_block_link).children(a.icon);

    /* Animate in; show everything */
    this_block_text.animate(e.eventType(...));
    this_block_image.animate(e.eventType(...));
    this_block_link.animate(e.eventType(...));
    this_block_link_icon.animate(e.eventType(...));
});
```

Note 1: Yes, i'm using cached_blocks in other part of the code.

Comment: `hover()` is soon [gonna be deprecated](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11731). I suggest you use `on()` with both mouse events.

Comment: Well, at least the very beginning of event handler is easily optimized: why wrap `this_block` with `jQuery` call when it's already a jQuery-wrapped object? The same with most of these wrapper calls.

Comment: @elclanrs That would be this: `.on({ mouseenter: fn1, mouseleave: fn2 });`, right?

Comment: To be fair, I don't think you'll get significant performance by caching this painstakingly. What you want to avoid is re-running queries over the entire document, or re-running the same query every time the event is triggered, compared to just once. (I.e. you want to reduce the complexity by an order of magnitude, not by a few calls over a small scope.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be repeating code for no good reason?

```
var cached_blocks = jQuery('.block-link');

cached_blocks.on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    var this_block = jQuery(this),
        this_block_text = this_block.children('div.text'),
        this_block_image = this_block.children('div.image'),
        this_block_link = this_block.children('div.link'),
        this_block_link_icon = this_block.children('a.icon');

    this_block_text.animate({something: (e.type==='mouseenter' ? 0 : 400)});
    this_block_image.animate({top: (e.type==='mouseenter' ? 10 : 200)});
    this_block_link.animate({left: (e.type==='mouseenter' ? 300 : 40)});
    this_block_link_icon.animate({right: (e.type==='mouseenter' ? 0 : 1400)});
});
```

Unless you are using the variables containing the text/image/link... elements somewhere else aswell, caching them just to use with animate() on the next line is a waste of space.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can bind `mouseout` and `mouseover` with the same callback closure `($element.on("mouseout mouseover", callback))`, and detect which event is inside the closure with something like `e.type == "mouseout"`.

In your code you are doing

```
this_block_text = jQuery(this_block).children(div.text)
```

and then

```
jQuery(this_block_text).animate(..);
```

why not this?

```
this_block_text.animate(..)
```

`this_block_text` is already a jQuery object

Comment: Also, the suggestion that @raina77ow did, relate with the final of my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(this_block_text).animate(..);
jQuery(this_block_image).animate(..);
jQuery(this_block_link).animate(..);
jQuery(this_block_link_icon).animate(..);
```

there is no need to write them as jQuery(...) because this_block_text, this_block_image etc. are already jQuery objects.

```
this_block_text.animate()
```

will run.

Also using $.() instead of jQuery() is better and cleaner.

And $('div.block-link') is faster than $('.block-link')

Answer (score 1):

The thing which stands out the most in this code is how often you are calling `jQuery`. If you already have a jQuery object, there is no need to call jQuery again.

This:

```
var cached_blocks = jQuery(".block-link");
jQuery(cached_blocks).hover(...);
```

does the same thing as:

```
var cached_blocks = jQuery(".block-link");
cached_blocks.hover(...);
```

If you're not going to reuse `cached_blocks` there's not going to be any performance improvement from having it, so you could simplify the code to just:

```
jQuery(".block-link").hover(...);
```

If the elements are already on the page, I'd simplify the code down to:

```
var links = jQuery(".block-link");

var parts = {
    text: links.children("div.text"),
    image: links.children("div.image"),
    link: links.children("div.link"),
    icon: links.children("a.icon")
};

links.hover(function() {
    parts.text.animate(..);
    parts.image.animate(..);
    parts.link.animate(..);
    parts.icon.animate(..);
}, function() {
    parts.text.animate(..);
    parts.image.animate(..);
    parts.link.animate(..);
    parts.icon.animate(..);
});
```

Without knowing what sort of animations you want to do, I can't simplify it any more, but I suspect you won't need so many calls to animate either.

Comment: The problem with your code is, if I do that, every block-link is affected with the animation, instead of only happening with only one where the hover is.